# React js material ui autocomplete chips with a button inside

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

[image]
As you can see from the image, the first input field is a working autocomplete that makes use of the chips.

The second input field is always an autocomplete but not functional, inside which a button has been inserted inside the TextField.

What I would like to do is to put them together, that is to have an autocomplete as in the first case but to have a button inside to give the user experience of the modern user.

Can you help me out?

Link: [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-w24ui)

Code:

```
/* eslint-disable no-use-before-define */
import React from "react";
import { Button, InputAdornment } from "@material-ui/core";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  root: {
    width: 500,
    "& > * + *": {
      marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
    }
  }
}));

export default function Tags() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites"
          />
        )}
      />
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        id="tags-outlined"
        options={top100Films}
        getOptionLabel={option => option.title}
        defaultValue={[top100Films[13]]}
        filterSelectedOptions
        renderInput={params => (
          <TextField
            {...params}
            variant="outlined"
            label="filterSelectedOptions"
            placeholder="Favorites"
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="end">
                  <Button variant="contained" color="primary" size="small">
                    Subscribe
                  </Button>
                </InputAdornment>
              )
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

const top100Films = [
  { title: "The Shawshank Redemption", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Dark Knight", year: 2008 },
  { title: "12 Angry Men", year: 1957 },
  { title: "Schindler's List", year: 1993 },
  { title: "Pulp Fiction", year: 1994 },
  { title: "The Lord of the Rings: The Return of the King", year: 2003 },
  { title: "The Good, the Bad and the Ugly", year: 1966 }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but in the second Autocomplete, you are overriding the InputProps in {...params}. In order for the Autocomplete and button to work, you must set your InpurProps like this:

```
renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Select a place"
      placeholder="Place"
      InputProps={{
        ...params.InputProps,
        endAdornment: (
          <Stack direction="row" spacing={1}>
            <Button>Subscribe</Button>
            {params.InputProps.endAdornment}
          </Stack>
        ),
      }}
    />
  )}
```

Above sample used mui v5.